# Send Alamofire request with parameters and also image in HTTP body

Tags: swift, swift2, uiimage, alamofire, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I have an Alamofire request

```
let parameters = ["key1":value1, "key2":value2, "keyn":valueN] as [String: AnyObject]

Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: ["Authorization": auth_token]).validate().responseObject() {
// etc 
}
```

But I need to add a jpg image under an "image" key to the body of the HTTP request, how can I do this? I'm having trouble finding a simple Alamofire solution for this. I need to keep the current parameters but also send an image along with the POST in the body of the request

Comment: I would highly recommend not uploading images in the body, even as a base64. It would be preferable to send the images to a bucket and then send up the url location of the image. Otherwise you'll be needless burning a lot of ram on image uploads

Answer (score 1):

How about converting the image to base64?

```
if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.30)
    {
        let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    }
```

*I'm compressing the quality here as well.

Comment: the API I'm working with specifically doesn't want Base64 but the image itself in the HTTP body. Never uploaded a pic before so this is all very new to me

Comment: @TommyK did you find how to do that.. I too need to send my json in http body along with images too as multipart